# MySQL COUNT() GROUP BY subquery(?) to count purchases on multiple items per month

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, subquery

I'm using MySQL and i'd like to count the number of purchases of multiple items by the month in which each item was purchased. My table is called "items_purchased", the items are listed by "item_id", and the purchase date is a timestamp called "purchase_date".

here's my query so far:

```
SELECT items_purchased.item_id, items_purchased.purchase_date, 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE(purchase_date), '%m %y') AS monthYear FROM items_purchased
```

The results in plain english would be something like this:

item_id=3: 2 purchases in june 2011, 3 purchases in july 2011
item_id=2: 1 purchase in june 2011, 7 purchases in july 2011

any help to help me figure out how to do the appropriate COUNT() and/or GROUP BY statements (or whatever else i may need) to determine the per month purchases for each item_id would be greatly appreciated!

thank you,
tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(purchase_date) as year, DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%M') as month, COUNT(item_id) as cnt
FROM items_purchased
GROUP BY YEAR(purchase_date), MONTH(purchase_date)
ORDER BY year, month, cnt
```

If you want per-itemID counts, add 'item_id' to the end of the GROUP BY clause. This'll just count how many itemIDs show up in any given year/month, but not break it down per-item.

Comment: awesome Marc, followed what you said and this works, thanks so much!